# boto3 how to get all tags for a single ec2 instance and append new ones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, taglist

My task would seem to be simple but I am not seeing in the documentation nor on the web. I have an ec2 instance id and I want to get all the currents tags and add additional ones. All I see for examples is how to get all instances running or in a vpc. The boto2 document only shows how to retrieve a single tag or multiple but not all.

Answer (score 0):

These days, you should be using [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

To **retrieve the tags** of an instance, use [`describe_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances).

It returns:

```json
{
    'Reservations': [
        {
            'Instances': [
                {
                    'Tags': [
                        {
                            'Key': 'string',
                            'Value': 'string'
                        },
```

To **set the tags** on an instance, use [`create_tags()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags), specifying the ID of the instance.